# Static routes in HP-UX

Tags: networking, routing, hp-ux

I need to set static route in HP-UX. I edited /etc/rc.config.d/netconf file and added new entry for my route:

```
ROUTE_DESTINATION[1]="10.105.2.0"
ROUTE_MASK[1]="255.255.255.0"
ROUTE_GATEWAY[1]="192.1.1.219"
ROUTE_COUNT[1]="1"
ROUTE_ARGS[1]=""
```

But after rebooting HP-UX I don't have this route in routing table (checked with netstat -rn).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documented `/etc/rc.config.d/netconf`:

```
# ROUTE_DESTINATION:  Destination host or network IP address in decimal-dot
#                     notation, or hostname (in /etc/hosts) or network name
#                     (in /etc/networks), preceded by the word "host" or "net";
#                     or simply the word "default".
#
# ROUTE_MASK:         Subnetwork mask in decimal-dot notation, or C language
#                     hexadecimal notation.  This is an optional field.
#                     An IP address/subnet mask pair uniquely identifies
#                     a subnet to be reached. If a subnet mask is not given,
#                     then the system will assign the longest subnet mask
#                     of the configured network interfaces to this route.
#                     If there is no matching subnet mask, then the system
#                     will assign the default network mask as the route's
#                     subnet mask.
```

I Don't have a HPUX that I can play with right now, but based on this documentation you could try:

```
ROUTE_DESTINATION[1]="net 10.105.2.0"
ROUTE_MASK[1]=""
ROUTE_GATEWAY[1]="192.1.1.219"
ROUTE_COUNT[1]="1"
ROUTE_ARGS[1]=""
```

or

```
ROUTE_DESTINATION[1]="net 10.105.2.0"
ROUTE_MASK[1]="255.255.255.0"
ROUTE_GATEWAY[1]="192.1.1.219"
ROUTE_COUNT[1]="1"
ROUTE_ARGS[1]=""
```

or

```
ROUTE_DESTINATION[1]="10.105.2.0/24"
ROUTE_MASK[1]=""
ROUTE_GATEWAY[1]="192.1.1.219"
ROUTE_COUNT[1]="1"
ROUTE_ARGS[1]=""
```

Comment: Thanks. `ROUTE_DESTINATION[1]="net 10.105.2.0"` works for me. I should be more careful.